# Xamarin Forms Android Build error - Missing File, UniversalApiContract.winmd

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and am developing an Android/iOS/UWP app using Visual Studio 2019 with latest updates.  All NuGet packages in all projects are up to date.  Also, Windows 10 Pro has the latest Windows updates.

I've been all over the internet looking for a solution to this.  I get the following error when building with the Android project.  Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Thanks.

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\10.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd'.
File name: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.19041.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\10.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd'
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MetadataResolver.Resolve(String assemblyName)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(MetadataResolver resolver)    PulsedFrequency.Android

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Xamarin Forms project and added all the NuGet packages and my code to it, rebuilt and it worked.  Not my favorite way to do things, but I'm finally out of DLL hell.
The problem was that somehow I had added the above library to the Android project and you can't do that because it's a UWP library.  That's why the error was occurring.